# Convert timestamp column values to epoch in PostgreSQL select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I need to convert timestamp values to epoch in a `SELECT` query.
Please find the below sample table and expected result.

Sample table:

```
select * from log;
```

```
id        | 3
time      | 2016-03-30 18:44:19.189513
data1     | NONE
data3     | NONE
data4     | NONE
```

Expected result:

```
id        | 3
time      | 1459343659
data1     | NONE
data3     | NONE
data4     | NONE
```

Log table is having n number of rows. Please find the below version details:

```
select version();

version                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [extract()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function:

```
select id, extract(epoch from time) as time, 
       data1, data2,data3
from log;
```

Apparently your column is not a timestamp column but a `varchar`, so you first need to cast that to a real timestamp before you can use `extract()`

```
select id, 
       extract(epoch from time::timestamp) as time, 
       data1, data2,data3
from log;
```

This will only work if all values in that column have the correct ISO format for a timestamp.

---

This teaches you, that you should

#### never store date, timestamp or time values in a `varchar` column!

Comment: I already tried this, I am getting error as "ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, character varying) does not exist"

Comment: @AnithaMani: you should have included that in your question. Please edit your question and add the output of `select version()`

Comment: @AnithaMani: ah I didn't read the error message carefully enough. See my updated answer

Comment: The only other thing I would add is the time zone. In that case you also need to use the "WITH TIME ZONE' in your sql statement. For example,     SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM <table column for timestamp>::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ) AS <NEW COLUMN> FROM <table name>. Change the values in < > based on your table/column names.